# Choosing between "have" and "have had"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, tenses

So other day I stumbled upon this one particular grammar question, which seems to have many right answers according to my friends.

**Question**: I (have) my hair cut whenever it gets too long.

My first answer was: I *have had* my hair cut whenever it gets too long.

But I could not state a proper reasoning for this, as it mostly was my gut feeling. I showed it to some of my friends and they also told me that it is correct but could not provide any proper reasoning for the same. Then someone else told me that -

"I *have* my hair cut whenever it gets too long." is the right answer.

So my question is which one is correct and why?

**Ans 1:** I *have had* my hair cut whenever it gets too long.

**Ans 2:**  I *have* my hair cut whenever it gets too long.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: "I (have) my hair cut whenever it gets too long." is not a question. What is it supposed to mean? And how can anyone tell what the "right" answer is, unless they're taking lessons from the author?

Comment: 'Have had' sounds past tense - (in the past, I _have had_ my hair cut...)

Answer (score 5):

> I have my hair cut whenever it gets too long.

This is an admission of something you do on a regular basis.

You're saying that you regularly get your hair cut when it gets too long.

It's like saying: "I eat whenever I'm hungry."

> I have had my hair cut whenever it gets too long.

This is an admission that you've gotten your hair cut in the past. It says nothing about the future (although that can be implied).

You're saying that, in the past, you've had your hair cut when it has gotten too long.

It's like saying: "I have eaten whenever I've been hungry."

Also, I don't think your sentence is grammatically correct. It should be:

> I have had my hair cut <s>whenever it gets</s> **when it has gotten** too long.

Comment: In British English 'gotten' is used very little if at all. We would say "I have had my hair cut when it has _got_ too long." or "I have had my hair cut whever it has _got_ too long." Also I believe "I have had my hair cut _whenever_ it has gotten too long." would be correct American English.

Comment: @BoldBen, You're probably right IMO. But it may be a moot point. Looking at the bigger picture, I don't see any use for that sentence *at all* (with "got" or "gotten", British or American). First of all, it states the obvious. Second, it would require a scenario that begs such a response. Is there such a scenario in the real world?

Comment: "I have had my hair cut _because_ it had got too long". To use _whenever_ doesn't really make sense.